# typescript - create type that denotes the set of even numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Can anyone know how to create this kind of type?
if 'evenNumbers" is the name of the type, i want for example that:

```
let a:evenNumbers = 3
```

will return error and

```
let a:evenNumbers = 4
```

will not.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be happy to be proven wrong, but I feel that TypeScript's type system is not powerful enough to express that. Maybe, it would be possible to encode a version of Peano Numbers at the type-level, but then your expressions would look more like `let: evenNumbers = S(S(S(Z)))` and `let: evenNumbers = S(S(S(S(Z))))`, because AFAIK TypeScript doesn't allow literal overloading.

Comment: Yes, probably not possible, because among other reasons unlike C++, TS does not provide arithmetic on generic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which numbers are valid for a given type.

e.g.

```
type EvenNumber= 2 | 4 | 6 | 8;

let foo: EvenNumber= 8;
let bar: EvenNumber= 9; // ERROR: 9 isn't even 
let baz: EvenNumber= 10; // ERROR: 10 is even, but it isn't defined as part of the Even type.
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20EvenNumber%20%3D%202%20%7C%204%20%7C%206%20%7C%208%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20EvenNumber%20%3D%208%3B%0D%0Alet%20bar%3A%20EvenNumber%20%3D%209%3B%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%209%20isn't%20even%20%0D%0Alet%20baz%3A%20EvenNumber%20%3D%2010%3B%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%2010%20is%20even%2C%20but%20it%20isn't%20defined%20as%20part%20of%20the%20Even%20type.)

That's great and all, but as you can see I've pointed out the problem with this approach.

Though 10 is even, it still errors because it wasn't defined as part of the `EvenNumber` type.

So you can redefine `EvenNumber` as `type EvenNumber= 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10;`

Great! Now `let baz: Even = 10;` will work, but what about `let baz: Even = 12;`?

So you'd have to find a way of listing every even number for the type definition. That's probably best done using some code generation tool, rather than by hand!

So there we are, we now have a type definition which only allows even numbers. Unfortunately the file it lives in must now be incredibly large, and likely causes problems for compilers and IDEs alike!

Does this answer the question? Yes!

Is this actually usable in the real world? Not even close.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! Very clever. I am so used to working in languages with *real* integers (i.e. infinitely many of them) that I totally forgot that TypeScript has only a finite number of integers and you could just list them all out. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a type like this and throw `Error` from `constructor()` method:

```
export class EvenNumber{
  value: number;
  constructor(value: number){
    if(value % 2 != 0){
      throw new Error('not even');
    }
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Since EvenNumber is a custom type, you should use constructor to instantiate it:

```
let a:EvenNumber = new EvenNumber(3);
```

Comment: when i write  let even:EvenNumber = 2 i get the error : Type '2' is not assignable to type 'EvenNumber'.

Comment: @Guyb That's because `2` is not assignable to type `EvenNumber`, which is a class.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in 4.1 you can define it but with stirings

```
type EvenDigit = '0' | '2' | '4' | '6' | '8' 
type OtherDigits = `${number}` | ''
type EvenNumber = `${OtherDigits}${EvenDigit}`

const n1 : EvenNumber = '23423098' 
// correct

const n2 : EvenNumber = '23423095' 
// Type '"23423095"' is not assignable to type 'EvenDigit | `${number}0` | `${number}2` | `${number}4` | `${number}6` | `${number}8`'.
```